# SVN checkout and Subclipse both not working

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, subclipse

I am VERY new to this concept of svn and hence this might sound to be a trivial question to you. But I really need help on this one as I haven't been able to find a way out even after searching online for more than an hour now.

I want to get the source code of [this project](http://code.google.com/p/android-launcher-plus/source/checkout).

As you see in the **[Browse](http://code.google.com/p/android-launcher-plus/source/browse/)** section, all the source codes are available.

I installed ***tortoiseSVN*** and used the **SVN Checkout** option by right clicking on the folder.

But I get this error in tortoiseSVN :

```
Command: Checkout from http://android-launcher-plus.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/android-launcher-plus-read-only, revision HEAD, Fully recursive, Externals included  
Error: URL  
Error:  'http://android-launcher-plus.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/android-launcher-plus-read-only'  
Error:  doesn't exist  
Completed!
```

I even installed [subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/) and tried to ***Import project in eclipse*** by checking out but I got the same error.

Is there any other way to get the codes from the site I mentioned ? (The thing is that I need to make a launcher application for andorid and it would really have been very helpful if I could get those codes somehow)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The URL to the repository is `http://android-launcher-plus.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/`

The `android-launcher-plus-read-only` bit is the local folder you want to put it in. You've missed the space inbetween them.

Try using the url `http://android-launcher-plus.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/`

EDIT: Using the URL above I managed to sucessfully checkout from that SVN repo from Mac OSX terminal

Comment: +1. for explanation related to `android-launcher-plus-read-only`

Comment: Oh! How can I ever thank you enough!! It worked like a charm now! Thanks a ton!

Comment: Am new to svn. Had no idea about the local folder. And I thought that the url shouldn't contain space so I removed it myself. How very silly of me. Thanks again. Upvoted and accepted! :)

Comment: That's fine, everyone has to learn somewhere. If you're using the command line and you don't include a local folder name then it will checkout to a folder called `trunk` (the last part of the SVN url). In tortoiseSVN this probably isn't a problem as the GUI sorts everything out for you. Its included in google code because `android-launcher-plus-read-only` is more descriptive than `trunk` haha!

Comment: DUDE. I've had this problem for months. As a work-around, I once manually copied every single file from a repository to build my own library. FFFFFFFFFFF. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The url is simply `http://android-launcher-plus.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/`, you read the instructions wrong.

As Thomas (more helpfully than me) noted, the example checkout command line includes the name of the project so it would be checked out to a directory called `android-launcher-plus-read-only`, not because it's an integral part of the command.

Comment: Thank you so very much for your answer! As I said, I am new to svn and had no idea that the last part was actually the name of the local folder. Thank you so very much. Upvoted you! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try checking out

```
svn checkout http://android-launcher-plus.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ Your_folder_path
```

and you should be done.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I did as I was told and it worked! Thanks! Upvoted you! :)